# Use NTEventLogAppender twice: in Tomcat and in my webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I'm trying to use NTEventLogAppender in [Tomcat log4j configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j) AND in my WebApp log4j configuration:

- case A) I declare the appender just in Tomcat: it works* !
- case B) I declare the appender just in my webapp: it works* !
- case C) I declare the appender in Tomcat and in my webapp: FAILED

*it works mean that I could see related events in Windows event viewer.

My question is how to fix case C? :

- Tomcat logs are visible into the event viewer but not my webapp logs.
- NTEventLogAppender static code doesn't work from my webapp startup.

I overrides "NTEventLogAppender" java classe(following [implementation](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/nt/NTEventLogAppender.java?view=markup)) to debug:

- the first `loadLibrary("NTEventLogAppender.amd64.dll")` return `"already loaded in another classloader"` error;
- then the appender try to load 32bits version (`"NTEventLogAppender.dll"`) without success (cause my host is 64bits).

So I made a hack to this static part to load another DLL from TMP directory:

```
static {
  LogLog.warn("************************************************ NTEventLogAppender");
  String fileToLoad="C:\\TMP\\nt\\NTEventLogAppender.amd64.dll";
try {
  System.load(fileToLoad);
  LogLog.warn(String.format("load '%s' OK", fileToLoad));
} catch(java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
  LogLog.error(String.format("unable to load %s : %s", fileToLoad, e.getMessage()), e);
}
```

In this case, [`load(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016391/difference-between-system-load-and-system-loadlibrary-in-java) works but I got the following error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.mycompany.logger.NTEventLogAppender.registerEventSource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
at com.mycompany.logger.NTEventLogAppender.registerEventSource(Native Method)
at com.mycompany.logger.NTEventLogAppender.<init>(NTEventLogAppender.java:62)
at com.mycompany.logger.NTEventLogAppender.<init>(NTEventLogAppender.java:32)
```

Seems like the library is accessible but not the function. Do you have any idea to make NTEventLogAppender accessible from Tomcat and webapp ?

Library is maybe not thread safe ?

For me the appender should be declared one time for all in tomcat configuration, then as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#I.27m_encountering_classloader_problems_when_using_JNI_under_Tomcat), I tryed to put DLL into  `"$CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib"` and I add this directory to my `java.library.path` but it doesn't work : I got no tomcat logs event in event viewer.

Any idea on how to fix it ?

Comment: Related: [.dll already loaded in another classloader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030792/dll-already-loaded-in-another-classloader)

Comment: Thanks I see this question. Tomorrow I will try to loadLibrary and make this error non fatal (avoid to load copy of dll) to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, We need to remove log4j jar completely from the webapp and keep only one instance of the following files into `$CATALINA_BASE\lib\`  directory :

- `NTEventLogAppender<*>.dll`
- `log4j.properties`
- and `log4j-1.2.17.jar`

I was thinking that was already done but that was not the case, and `grep` save my life:

```
cd webapp\WEB-INF\lib && grep -rnl NTEventLogAppender
```

The error "already loaded in another classloader" (and other side effects) was due to a dependency of my web app which includes log4j classes :

`<dependency><groupId>org.graylog2</groupId><artifactId>gelfj</artifactId><version>1.1.10</version></dependency>`

By removing it I was able to use diagnostic appender for my webapp and for tomcat logs.

NB/ (Even with the help of [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888360/log4j-in-tomcat-lib-and-in-each-webapp)) I was not able to duplicate `log4j.properties` (one for tomcat and one for my webapp) so I keep only one global configuration file (from tomcat lib directory).